# Unit Test in Rails with resque-scheduler. Manually enqueue scheduled tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, resque, resque-scheduler

Using resque-scheduler to create Resque jobs in the future, how do you unit test?

Code to enqueue the tasks:

```
i = 0
installed_apps.each_slice(3) do |slice|
  slice.each do |installed_app_id|
    Resque.enqueue_in((5*i).minutes, ReinstallApp, installed_app_id)
  end
  i = i+1
end
```

Code used to manually run regular Rescue tasks within a unit test:

```
def run_worker_simulation
  worker = Resque::Worker.new('connection')
  job = worker.reserve
  worker.perform(job)
end
```

The task runs fine when queued as a regular Resque job. The problem is that this doesn't run any resque-scheduler scheduled tasks, even ones with Resque.enqueue_in(0.minutes, ...). How do you manually run scheduled tasks?

Comment: I ended up using Resque.enque instead of enqueue_in when Rails.env == 'test'

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modifying your code do have an exception for the test environment, it's better practice to build your tests around functionality as you've built it.

I'd suggest simply building a test to check to make sure that Resque receives an `enqueue_in` call.  It's generally safe to assume that `resque-scheduler` will have sufficient test coverage, however, you could run the tests for that gem if that makes you more comfortable with the overall soundness of your code.

Comment: Right, but how do you run a job that has been enqueued with `enqueue_in`? I couldn't figure out how to build a test around it.

Comment: You wouldn't run the job in the test environment.  You would mock / stub your expected results.  You *could* write tests around the code of the background job as well.

Comment: If you're using the 'mocha' gem, you can mock the enqueue_in call instead of really invoking it: Resque.expects(:enqueue_in).with(...<your expected args>...)